# File Copy failing to create files with same name

Tags: c#, .net

I am copying files from one location to another. I encountered an issue where sometimes a file with the same name would try to save and it would break the program. So I added the logic below to add a number to the filename before copying it:

```
                int counter = 0;
                try
                {
                    File.Copy(FileToCopy, FileToSave);

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    string CurrentFileName = FileToSave.Split('\\', '\\')[4];
                    string CurretFilePrefix = CurrentFileName.Split('.')[0];
                    string CurrentFileSuffix = CurrentFileName.Split('.')[1];
                    string UpdatedFileName = CurretFilePrefix + "_" + counter + "." + CurrentFileSuffix;
                    File.Copy(FileToCopy, UpdatedFileName);
                    counter++;
                }
```

However, this is now causing a crash saying the file already exists:

[image]

When I check the file does not exist:

[image]

Why am I getting this exception? How do I save copies of these files?

Comment: Shouldn't that counter variable be in a loop with what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: You are getting the exception because the file DOES exist but you are looking in the wrong place. You stripped off the directory in the process of creating the new file name.

Comment: @LarsTech I didn't want to post the entire program, it is in a foreach.

Comment: @Ian Mercer You found the issue. Please put as an answer.

Comment: A `for each` of what?  That doesn't make any sense.  Your posted code can only handle a blank or a 0.  The Path class is your friend, you should be using it a lot in your code.

Comment: Does the problem go away if you do a Clean before a Build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good approach to this problem would include (i) a loop; (ii) use of `Path` expressions; (iii) avoidance of `try-catch` when you can test if the file exists; (iv) use of a specific Exception for the extremely unlikely case that two threads or processes are trying to do this same copy at the same time and each get past the `File.Exists` check; (v) avoidance of while-true-forever loops as even the best code can contain mistakes that could cause a spin-wait forever in production code on a server and it's better to instead have an exception that tells you when something has gone wrong.

```
        int counter = 0;
        string proposedDest = dest;
        while(counter < 5000)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(proposedDest))
            {
                try
                {
                    File.Copy(fileToCopy, proposedDest);
                    break;
                }
                catch (IOException ex) when ((uint)ex.HResult == 0x80070050)
                {
                }
            }
            counter++;
            proposedDest = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(dest),
                Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dest) + 
                "_" + counter + Path.GetExtension(dest));
        }
        ;
        if (counter == 5000) 
           throw new Exception($"Could not copy file {fileToCopy} too many retries");
```

[A better approach would also not use hard coded constants littered through the code ;)]

Answer (score 1):

As `CurrentFileName` is relative, you are trying to save the file in the location of your executable. Check that directory if your file exists.

Also, there are much better ways to find if the file exists, and also to get the filename and extension of a given file.

i.e. you should use the [`File.Exists`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to determine if the file exists, instead of using exceptions for flow control

```
if (File.Exists(FileToSave))
{
   FileToSave = GetNewFileName(FileToSave)
}
try
{
  File.Copy(FileToCopy, FileToSave);
}
catch (Exception)
{
  //something went really wrong
}
```

You should also use the `Path` methods for getting parts of the name, instead of "knowing" to get the fifth part of the filename ([`Path.GetExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

```
private string GetNewFileName(string oldFileName){
   var counter = 0;
   var extension = Path.GetExtension(oldFileName);
   var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(oldFileName);
   var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(oldFileName);

   var newFileName = Path.Combine(directory, 
      string.Format("{1}_{2}{3}", filename, counter, extension);

   while (File.Exists(newFileName)){
      counter++;
      newFileName = Path.Combine(directory, 
        string.Format("{1}_{2}{3}", filename, counter, extension);
   }

   return newFileName;
}
```

Comment: The folder is generated before trying to save the file. That isn't whats causing the exception.

Comment: The path in the exception message doesn't say "C:\ScrumWorks..." so that's not where it's trying to save to.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the folder exists, as you are not saving in that folder. You've stripped the path of of `CurrentFileName`, so by default, it goes to the path of your .exe file.

Comment: BTW you should use `Path.Combine` not `string.format` to combine path elements otherwise this code will not work correctly on other OS platforms.

Answer (score 0):

use this instead:

```
string CurrentFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileToSave);
string CurretFilePrefix = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileToSave);
string CurrentFileSuffix = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileToSave);
string UpdatedFileName = CurretFilePrefix + "_" + counter + "." + CurrentFileSuffix;
```

Then you have

```
File.Copy(FileToCopy, UpdatedFileName);
```

Are you sure this shouldn't be

```
File.Copy(FileToSave, UpdatedFileName); // FileToSave instead of FileToCopy
```

Comment: I am still getting the same exception.

Comment: Maybe it's because it already exists from other tries at running your code?

Comment: This code is still stripping the directory path from `FileToSave`.

Comment: @IanMercer, that is true. But I don't know the intention of the OP.